ERROR: ‘Could not open root directory: [14] not found’ I got this error from the initial stage of installing Linux mint
Error photo
I went to boot menu and select my USB then I got this screen. I don’t know why this happening. I’m new to Linux, Can anyone help me how to solve this.
I don't know how to solve this
I have acer laptop with windows 11 | processor: AMD RYZEN 3 3250U
